# Login ajax jsp servlet: Welcome page loading in div reserved for error message

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am developing a Login with jsp, servlet and ajax. When I enter the password incorrectly it shows the error message, but when I enter the correct key loads welcome.jsp into the div reserved for the error message.

From **servlet** I send the message as response and with **javascript** adding this message to the `div id="text"` content.

Code JSP:

```
<body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#submitLogin').click(function (event) {
                var nombreVar = $('#txtUsuario').val();
                var apellidoVar = $('#txtPassword').val();

                $.post('ServletLoguin', {
                    nombre: nombreVar,
                    apellido: apellidoVar

                }, function (responseText) {

                    $('#texto').html(responseText);

                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <form id="formLogin" >
        <label>ingrese usuario</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtUsuario"><br> <br>
        <label>ingrese clave</label>
        <input type="password" id="txtPassword"><br><br>
        <input type="button" id="submitLogin" value="Iniciar Sesion">
    </form>
    <div id="tabla">
        <p id="texto" style="color:red;"></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Code Java servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {       

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String usuario = request.getParameter("nombre");
    String password = request.getParameter("apellido");

    try {
        CallableStatement cl = Conexion.getConexion().prepareCall("{call SGVC_Login(?,?)}");
        cl.setString(1, usuario);
        cl.setString(2, password);
        ResultSet rs = cl.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {

            HttpSession sesionLoguin = request.getSession();
            sesionLoguin.setAttribute("perfil", rs.getString(12));
            sesionLoguin.setAttribute("nom", rs.getString(5));
            sesionLoguin.setAttribute("apePaterno", rs.getString(3));
            sesionLoguin.setAttribute("apeMaterno", rs.getString(4));
            sesionLoguin.setAttribute("codUser", rs.getString(1));

            if (sesionLoguin.getAttribute("perfil").equals("TVENTA") || sesionLoguin.getAttribute("perfil").equals("TCOBRANZA")) {

                //request.getRequestDispatcher("principal1.jsp").forward(request, response);
                response.sendRedirect("principal1.jsp");
                //request.getRequestDispatcher("ServletRegistrarVenta.java").forward(request, response);                    

            } else {
                //request.getRequestDispatcher("principal2.jsp").forward(request, response);
                response.sendRedirect("principal2.jsp");
            }

        } else {
            response.setContentType("text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
            out.println("error");

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("error " + e);
    }       

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using ajax, it will not reload your page. So either you can use `form.submit()` or from your ajax call back method use `window.location.href = '<your_page>.jsp'` after passing ***success*** as response like

```
if(reponseText == 'principal1')
    window.location.href = 'principal1.jsp';
else if(reponseText == 'principal2')
    window.location.href = 'principal2.jsp';
else
    $('#texto').html(responseText);
```

>

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {       

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
String usuario = request.getParameter("nombre");
String password = request.getParameter("apellido");

try {
    CallableStatement cl = Conexion.getConexion().prepareCall("{call SGVC_Login(?,?)}");
    cl.setString(1, usuario);
    cl.setString(2, password);
    ResultSet rs = cl.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {

        HttpSession sesionLoguin = request.getSession();
        sesionLoguin.setAttribute("perfil", rs.getString(12));
        sesionLoguin.setAttribute("nom", rs.getString(5));
        sesionLoguin.setAttribute("apePaterno", rs.getString(3));
        sesionLoguin.setAttribute("apeMaterno", rs.getString(4));
        sesionLoguin.setAttribute("codUser", rs.getString(1));

        if (sesionLoguin.getAttribute("perfil").equals("TVENTA") || sesionLoguin.getAttribute("perfil").equals("TCOBRANZA")) {

            response.setContentType("text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
            out.write("principal1");         

        } else {
            response.setContentType("text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
            out.write("principal2");
        }

    } else {
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
        out.write("error");

    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("error " + e);
}
```

}

Comment: remove this `response.sendRedirect("principal2.jsp");`
and use `out.println('principal2')` then check this and redirect from javascript using `window.location.href`

Comment: It works well. But still loading princial1.jsp into the <div> created for the error message. Please check this part of code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxxJC_OOfBR1OWcwT2ZwS05EVTg/view